# Entanglement and density matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Suppose I have a system composed of two subsystems (each is a 2-state system).

Let $$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B - |0\rangle_B \otimes |1\rangle_A)$$ be an entangled state of two subsystems A and B.

Let $\hat{\rho} = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ the same entangled state but described by a density matrix:

$$\hat{\rho} = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle_A \otimes |1\rangle_B - |0\rangle_B \otimes |1\rangle_A)(\langle 0|_A \otimes \langle 1|_B - \langle 0|_B \otimes \langle 1|_A)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle _A\langle 0|_A \otimes |1\rangle _B\langle 1|_B -|0\rangle _A\langle 1|_A \otimes |1\rangle _B\langle 0|_B - |1\rangle _A\langle 0|_A \otimes |0\rangle _B\langle 1|_B + |1\rangle _A\langle 1|_A \otimes |0\rangle _B\langle 0|_B) $$

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{4} c_i \rho_{Ai} \otimes \rho_{Bi}$$

And it was my understanding that a state that can be written like $\sum_{i=1}^{4} c_i \rho_{Ai} \otimes \rho_{Bi}$ is not an entangled state. So there is a problem becuase $\rho$ is supposed to be one, so I made a mistake somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You should use `\langle` and `\rangle` ($\langle\cdots\rangle$) instead of greater/lesser-than signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this formula, two requirement are mandatory if we want the state to be a separable one : $\sum_i c_i = 1$ and all the $\rho_{Ai}$ and $\rho_{Bi}$ are a density matrixes. In this case, only one of the two conditions are respected because $\sum_i c_i = 0 \ne 1$.

Comment: What is missing is that the $c_i$ have to be positive. Moreover, $\sum c_i=1$ is automatically satisfied as this is the trace of the total state (which is one by definition). (The only way the $c_i$ might *not* add up to 1 is if some of the $\rho$ don't have trace one, which is the case in your derivation.)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you'd like to establish an entanglement measure which is distinct from measures quantifying the purity of the state. Your state is \begin{equation} |\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |0_A\rangle|1_B\rangle - |1_A\rangle|0_B\rangle \right) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle - |10\rangle \right)\end{equation} The corresponding density operator is \begin{equation} \hat{\rho} = |\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi| = \frac{1}{2}\left( |01\rangle\langle01| + |10\rangle\langle10| - |01\rangle\langle10| - |10\rangle\langle01| \right). \end{equation} With the ordering of the two-particle basis $\{ |00\rangle,|10\rangle,|01\rangle,|11\rangle \}$ a possible matrix representation is \begin{equation} \underline{\underline{\rho}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) \end{equation}.

You can check for yourself that: $\underline{\underline{\rho}} = \underline{\underline{\rho}}^\dagger$ (the density matrix is Hermitian), $\mathrm{Tr}(\underline{\underline{\rho}})=1$ (unit trace) and $\mathrm{Tr}(\underline{\underline{\rho}}^2)=1$ (unit purity, because it is a pure state). It also has zero von Neumann entropy $S = -\mathrm{Tr}(\underline{\underline{\rho}} \log \underline{\underline{\rho}})$, yet again because it is a pure state.

However, to check for entanglement between the two subsystems A and B, you can trace out e.g. subsystem B to arrive at the reduced density matrix (RDM) of subsystem A: \begin{equation} \hat{\rho}_A = \mathrm{Tr}_B (\hat{\rho}) = \langle 0_B | \hat{\rho} | 0_B \rangle + \langle 1_B | \hat{\rho} | 1_B \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \left( |0_A\rangle\langle0_A| + |1_A\rangle\langle1_A| \right). \end{equation} This is basically asking how subsystem A looks like "forgetting" that B exists. If we started from a pure state for the whole system and we find a mixed state for A, i.e. we can't tell what state A is in, it means some information about A got lost while "forgetting" about B, and hence the two subsystems are entangled. Otherwise, if A is in a pure state, then A and B are essentially independent and there is no entanglement between the two. With the basis ordering $\{|0_A\rangle,|1_A\rangle\}$ one of the possible matrix representations now is \begin{equation} \underline{\underline{\rho}}_A = \frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right). \end{equation} You can again check that $\underline{\underline{\rho}}_A = \underline{\underline{\rho}}_A^\dagger$ (the RDM stays Hermitian), $\mathrm{Tr}(\underline{\underline{\rho}}_A)=1$ (the trace is still unity) however $\mathrm{Tr}(\underline{\underline{\rho}}_A^2)=1/2$, that is the purity is smaller than one, indicating a mixed state and hence that subsytem A is entangled with subsystem B. You can also check that the entropy now is $S = -\mathrm{Tr} \underline{\underline{\rho}}_A \log \underline{\underline{\rho}}_A = \log 2 > 0$, again indicating entanglement between subsystems A and B.

You can reiterate the above procedure with a separable state e.g. $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0_A\rangle+|1_A\rangle)|1_B\rangle$ and you'll find that the RDM for subsystem A (or subsytem B) is of unit purity and zero von Neumann entropy because the two subsystems aren't entangled.

Comment: I understand that the state is entangled, I defined it as it so it must be. What I do not understand is that it does not agree with the definition of an entangled state that I gave : "It cannot be written as $\rho =\sum _{i}w_{i}\rho _{i}^{A}\otimes \rho _{i}^{B}$" (that's what my teacher told me and wikipedia two)

Comment: Any density matrix can be written as a sum you've written, regardless of entanglement between subsystems A and B. The question is whether you can actually write the density matrix as a product of the density matrices of the two subsystems, without the sum, as Thomas Tappeiner pointed out. Try with a non-entangled state like $|\Psi\rangle=(|0_A\rangle+|1_A\rangle)|1_B\rangle/\sqrt{2}$. For this $\hat{\rho}=\hat{\rho}_A\otimes\hat{\rho}_B$ (no sum!) with $\hat{\rho}_B=|1\rangle\langle1|$ and $\hat{\rho}_A=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(\langle0|+\langle1|)/2$.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: As pointed out in the comments this answer is wrong still going to leave it here as I believe it it wrong to delete answers for this reason

Generally, by the Schmidt decomposition, every state in such a Hilberspace can be written as $\rho = \sum_i c_i \rho_i^A \otimes \rho_i^B$. So this can't be the correct condition for entanglement as obviously, this would allow for no entangled states.

The condition for a product state (or separable state)is rather that you can write $\rho = \rho^A \otimes \rho^B$ without the sum. I.e. that the element factors under the tensor product.  As you can see, this is not the case with your state.

Comment: "Extending the definition of separability from the pure case, we say that a mixed state is separable if it can be written as: $\rho =\sum _{i}w_{i}\rho _{i}^{A}\otimes \rho _{i}^{B}$, where the wi are positively valued probabilities and the ρ i A $\rho_i^A$'s and ρ i B $\rho_i^B$'s are themselves mixed states (density operators) on the subsystems A and B respectively. In other words, a state is separable if it is a probability distribution over uncorrelated states, or product states." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Concept

Comment: I took this formula from this wikipedia page